# MongoDB declare model and delete data

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, discord.js, commando

I'm trying to create a discord bot, specifically the married.

In the last topic, I implemented the marry command [MongoDB findOne() Cannot read property of null](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71705470/mongodb-findone-cannot-read-property-of-null)

Now, using the same logic, I'm trying to make a divorce command that will delete data from the database.

I do everything the same as there, but I get an error:

> OverwriteModelError: Cannot overwrite `Marry` model once compiled.

How do I correctly declare a model in order to find and delete data from the database?

```
const { Command } = require('discord.js-commando');
const Discord = require('discord.js');
const mongoose = require("mongoose");

mongoose.connect('mongodb+srv://admon:admin@cluster0.sobzp.mongodb.net/dbname?retryWrites=true&w=majority');

const marrySchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  userID : {
      type : mongoose.SchemaTypes.String,
      required : true
  },

  userPartnerID : {
      type : mongoose.SchemaTypes.String,
      required : true
  }
});

const Marry = mongoose.model('Marry', marrySchema);

module.exports = class DivorceCommand extends Command {
  constructor(client) {
    super(client, {
      name: 'divorce',
      memberName: 'divorce',
      group: 'test',
      description: 'Divorce',
      guildOnly: true,
      args: [
        {
          key: 'userToDivorce',
          prompt: 'Please indicate the member you wish to divorce.',
          type: 'member',
          default: 'isempty',
          wait: 0.0001
        }
      ]
    });
  }

  async run(message, { userToDivorce }) {
    const exists = await Marry.findOne({ userID: message.author.id });
    const divorce = await Marry.findOne({ userID: userToDivorce.id });

    if (userToDivorce == 'isempty') {
        return message.channel.send('Please indicate the member you wish to divorce.')}
    if (exists?.userID !== message.author.id) {
        return message.channel.send('You dont have a soul mate.')}
    if (divorce?.userID !== userToDivorce.id) {
        return message.channel.send('You are not married.')}
    if (exists?.userID === message.author.id && divorce?.userID === userToDivorce.id) {
        const embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
      .setDescription(`**Divorce**
    
      ${message.author}, Do you really want to divorce ${userToDivorce}?
  
      `);
    message.channel.send(embed).then(msg => {
      msg.react('✅').then(() => msg.react('❌'))
      setTimeout(() => msg.delete(), 30000)
      setTimeout(() => message.delete(), 30000);
    

      msg.awaitReactions((reaction, user) => user.id == message.author.id 
      && (reaction.emoji.name == '✅' || reaction.emoji.name == '❌'),
        { max: 1, time: 20000, errors: ['time'] })
      .then(collected => {
        const reaction = collected.first();
        if (reaction.emoji.name === '❌') {
            const embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
      .setDescription(`It seems that ${message.author} changed my mind.`);
      return message.channel.send(embed)}
    if (reaction.emoji.name === '✅') {
     
      Marry.deleteOne({ userID: message.author.id });
      Marry.deleteOne({ userID: userToDivorce.id });

      const embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
      .setDescription(`${message.author} and ${userToDivorce} no longer together.`);
    message.channel.send(embed)
    .catch(() => {
    });
      }
  }).catch(()=>{
    const embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
    .setDescription('There was no response after 20 seconds, the offer is no longer valid.');
    message.channel.send(embed)
    .then(message => {
      setTimeout(() => message.delete(), 10000)
    })
    .catch();
  });
}).catch(()=>{
});
}}};
```

I also tried to do this `const exists = await mongoose.marries.findOne({ userID: message.author.id });`

But I am getting an error

> An error occurred while running the command: TypeError: Cannot read property 'findOne' of undefined

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Cannot overwrite model once compiled Mongoose](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19051041/cannot-overwrite-model-once-compiled-mongoose)

Comment: @ZsoltMeszaros 
I tried everything from there, nothing helped..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you have already created Marry model and trying again either in multiple files or may be calling file more than once.

You may prevent by putting into if condition like

```
// put following model within condition to avoid error
// const Marry = mongoose.model('Marry', marrySchema);
if (!mongoose.modelNames().includes('Marry')) {
   mongoose.model('Marry', marrySchema);
}
const Marry = mongoose.model('Marry');
```

Comment: unfortunately does not help(

Comment: Have you written `mongoose.model('Marry', marrySchema);` into multiple files/places,? put above condition everywhere, better things create a new file  and put schema & model code there and include that file wherever required

Comment: Sorry, I didn’t do it in the first file, now everything seems to start up and work, but the data is not deleted, can there be errors here? `Marry.deleteOne({ userID: message.author.id });`

Comment: Did so and removed `Marry.deleteOne({ userID: message.author.id }, (err) => console.log(err))`